# Wordpress php version not supporting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I am updating PHP 7.2 to 7.4 or higher version it's not supporting. The website looks ugly.
https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/
[image]

Comment: Try to clear the cache of your web browser.

Comment: @mikewatawski did, it's not working...

Comment: It is possible that the theme is not compatible with the PHP version, or has not been updated yet. To check it properly, try to enable debugging. https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#example-wp-config-php-for-debugging

Comment: hmmm, but in my browser the website ui is okay

Comment: I downgraded to 7.2, so its work fine

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with old "Crayon Syntax Highlighter". Deactivated plugin and updated site PHP version 7.4, working fine now.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#example-wp-config-php-for-debugging